# Outdated codesniffer in MEQP2 composer.json for Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2, best-practice, coding-standards, code-analysis, phpcs

**How to correctly test against MEQP2 standard?**

Normally i use

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2
```

To supress errors a i use this:

```
//phpcs:ignore
```

or

```
//phpcs:disable PSR2
```

When using MEQP2 standards this will not work since composer requires old `"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.6.2"` that does not knew new phpcs syntax ...

> Note: Before PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.2.0, use // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine instead of // phpcs:ignore. The @codingStandards syntax is deprecated and will be removed in PHP_CodeSniffer version 4.0.

https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp/blob/c82070eca1075569578206430a6ef7975f7eeec1/composer.json#L8

---

What correct ...?

Use old phpcs ignore syntax and wait for an update or just update MEQP2 to `"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2"`?